# Set Label width in an itemRenderer - FLEX

Tags: apache-flex, label, itemrenderer

I am creating a Label in a Datagrid itemRenderer(extended from UIComponent) and right now I am setting the width of the label to some static value. I would like to create the label with 100% width. I do not want to use unScaledWidth because I am using link for the label so the link will be visible in the entire cell.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Am I missing something here or you should simply use `percentWidth`?

Answer (score 0):

Using percentWidth won't work. If you have only a `Label` in the ItemRenderer, make sure the Label has (if an mx item renderer) `autolayout="true"` (which is the default) and add `top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0"` to the `Label`. This will make your label take up the entire cell.

If you are using a Spark item renderer, the default layout of none is absolute layout, and simply adding `top="0" left="0" right="0" bottom="0"` to the `Label` should be enough.

On another note, updateDisplayList() and measure() are two of the most overused overrides in Flex. Always try to fix your problem with an MXML skin-class before you try to go the route of overriding updateDisplayList() and measure(). Most MX class drawing methods were implemented incorrectly with `private` methods doing most of the drawing and this makes extending those classes difficult.